# PHP can't use variable defined outside functions

Tags: php, xml, function, variables, undefined

I'm working on a project (simple XML CMS) just to learn some basic PHP.

First I include a config.php file which contains information about the CMS, and then I include a route.php for the URL routing and after that I include a functions.php file which is pretty similar to the WordPress' one (contains all the functions to for example load posts, tags, categories, etc.).

The structure looks like this:

```
<?php
    function latestProducts($amount = 6){
    }

    function products($search = FALSE, $query= '', $page = 1, $results = 5){
    }

    function getProductById($id){
    }

    function getProductTitleById($id){
    }

    function getProductByExcerpt($excerpt){
    }

    function getProductTitleByExcerpt($excerpt){
    }

    function getPost($id, $title, $description, $category, $excerpt = FALSE){
    }

    function getTitle(){
    }

    function breadcrumb($params, $first){
    }

    function pagination($page, $pages){
    }
?>
```

In config.php file I also use this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("products.xml") or die("The product XML file couldn't be loaded.");
```

But when I try to access $xml from within the functions I prepared in functions.php, I get a undefined variable notice. (I also tried placing the $xml variable inside the functions.php before the definition of the functions, but I got the same result.)

What is my mistake? I know it's simple; I just can't see clearly right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a scoping issue. The variables declared in the global scope aren't visible inside your functions. [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) explains what you can do about it. An overview:

- Import the variable from the global scope into the local scope of your function with `global $xml;` at the start of the function
- Store the variable as a key of the global variables superglobal, i.e. `$GLOBALS['xml']`
- Make the variable a static member of a class or create a singleton construction
- Pass the variable as an argument to every function that needs it

Note that when using a good OOP-style architecture these kind of problems can often be avoided, e.g. `$xml` would be a property of class instances that need direct access to the DOM object.

Answer (score 4):

Functions or methods do not have scopes outside them. In order to use a variable declared outside. Using `global` keyword, to tell the server to use the variable defined in higher scope.

```
$varname = "value";
function yourfunctionname() {
    //In order to use the variable declare you want to use the globally declared 
    global $varname;
    //now $varname will have "value` as its value

   //continue with your logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer and sorry for not picking it as the accepted asnwer!

Comment: @AKLP, no need to be sorry for every answers, you didn't accept. It's cool.... :)

Comment: Well, you spend your own time to try and help me :)

Answer (score 3):

`$xml` is global variable, you need to use `global` keyword.

```
function products($search = FALSE, $query= '', $page = 1, $results = 5){
    global $xml;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer and sorry for not picking it as the accepted asnwer!